# why guava cache support weakKeys() AND weakValues()

Tags: guava

Guava CacheBuilder support both weakKeys() and weakValues().
But if the values are collected, why do we want to still keep keys in Cache?
So if we just use weakKeys(), that should be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *not* the case that `weakKeys` means "collect the keys but keep the values," *nor* is it the case that `weakValues` means "collect the values but keep the keys."

What `weakKeys` does is say, "when there are no longer any strong references to the *key*, collect the entire entry."  What `weakValues` does is say, "when there are no longer any strong references to the *value*, collect the entire entry."  So when you use both, the entire entry is collected when *either* the key or the value has no strong references pointing to it.